# ArangoDB too much memory consumption even without any DB

Tags: database, arangodb

Im trying out ArangoDB for my project PoC. I have memory restriction in my project so I want to use RocksDB. When I start the arangodb [3.3.14] with no DB in place aranogb process is taking about ~215MB memory in centos 6 and also taking around 1GB of virtual memory. I've used the link (https://www.arangodb.com/2016/03/put-arangodb-spartan-mode/) to tune some parameters but still its too high for my project.

Is there is any way I can fix the memory for arangodb process say to use only 100mb and with 100mb of Virtual memory?

Comment: What storage engine are you using? You say you want to use RocksDB, but are you actually using it or wanting to? This could be one of the reasons why, as MMFiles uses alot of memory for cache.

Comment: I'm using rocksDB engine.

Comment: What is it that you want to do in the project? Such tight memory restrictions will do no good for performance and may limit what queries you can run at all. v3.4 (currently in release candidate phase) could be interesting for you (from changelog): "added experimental arangodb startup option `--javascript.enabled` to enable/disable the initialization of the V8 JavaScript engine. Only expected to work on single-servers and agency deployments." This could spare some memory. All built-in AQL functions have C++ implementations, so V8 isn't needed for that anymore.